# How to use htaccess to do this?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I got stuck at this point here, and I'm breaking my head trying to figure out why its not working!

This is want to get the url to look like

```
 example.com/news/top/
```

from

```
 example.com/index.php?view=news&task=top
```

but i need it that way that "task" can be something diffrent like

```
 example.com/index.php?view=news&task=newest
 example.com/index.php?view=news&task=help
 example.com/index.php?view=news&task=write
 ....
```

current .htaccess looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) index.php?view=$1&task=$2
```

If I visit www.example.com/news/ -> it only loads the index.php but does not pass ?view=news

If I visit www.example.com/news/top/ -> it works just fine.

But I need them both to work, adding a new line to .htaccess like :

```
RewriteRule ^news/ index.php?view=news
```

then visiting www.example.com/news/ works fine, but visiting www.example.com/news/top/ it will not be possible to get the value of task.

Please help me!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: RewriteRule ^news/top/ index.php?task=news&task=$1 [L] but this does not work

Comment: Seems your going for RESTful architecture. Read up on MVC patterns and you'll get a good idea of routing those requests. This might help: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/building-a-restful-php-server-understanding-the-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect access to index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?view=([^&]+)&task=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

# rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?view=$1&task=$2 [L]
```

The first redirects requests like `/index.php?view=news&task=foo` to `/news/foo/`. Then the second rule internally rewrites requests like `/news/foo/` back to `/index.php?view=news&task=foo`.

If all of your links already look like `/news/foo/`, then you won't need the first rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no htaccess veteran, but something like this might work:

```
RewriteRule /news/(.*) /index.php?view=news&task=$1 [L]
```

This should rewrite all requests to /news/abc to index.php?task=news&view=abc. The backreference `$1` stands for the first pattern in the RegEx that is surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: It keeps saying that it can't get "task" from url.